# TV show from 70s or 80s where jets join together to make giant robot

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, mecha

Really struggling to find a cartoon show I watched as a kid.

There were multiple pilots who flew jets / spaceships that would join together to make a giant robot. It was very *Voltron*-like, but the ships were not lions when flown individually. The pilots lived in a base which had a dome that would open and the base could go underground. I'm sure the ships were of a similar color scheme like *Voltron* and made up the all parts of the robot.

Any ideas or help would be awesome and appreciated

Comment: There was a second iteration of *Voltron* where it was a bunch of vehicles instead of lions. Like each limb was 2-4 vehicles.

Answer (score 17):

The show was Starvengers (Original Japanese title: Gettâ robo Jî)

YouTube video of the opening credits:

Description from IMDB:

> Soon after the events of the first *Getta Robo* series, Earth finds itself under attack by the Hyakki (Pandemonium) Empire and its fleet of horned battle robots. In response to the threat, the Getta labs re-fit their chief weapon: three advanced jets, capable of merging into three distinct robots. These are *Getta Dragun (Star Dragon)* the most powerful and oft-used formation; *Getta Rygar (Star Arrow)* designed for speed and aerial combat; and *Getta Poseidon (Star Poseidon)* built for strength and aquatic battle.

Comment: https://youtu.be/vGPNDvkcaiw     
 Here is the opening intro

Comment: Don't forget to accept in about a day and a half by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 7):

It could be *Vehicle Team Voltron*.

From Wikipedia:

> This Voltron Force consists of fifteen members, divided into three teams of five, known respectively as the Land, Sea, and Air Teams. Each team is specialized in gathering data or fighting in their area of expertise. Each team can combine their vehicles into a bigger machine. When necessary, all fifteen vehicles combine to form the mighty Voltron.

Here's a YouTube clip showing the vehicle team assembling Voltron:

Comment: that's pretty cool but it was definitely jet like ships that joined together, there were 4 or 5 I'm sure and all seemed younger characters .. the overweight character in the green suit I think was always eating , I'm sure there was a blue suited character  , I thought it was a variation of voltron but unless there's another it's something else entirely , it's been annoying me for years

Comment: @ped14 Oh that rings another bell...

Comment: I actually think there might only be 3 characters and when doing my searching it's very getter robo .. but it was in english and I can't find an episode of starvengers to check if the base was in it but the 3 jets / aircraft joining together is identical and the overweight character looks to be the one minus the suits which could be my memory tbh ,

Comment: https://youtu.be/dhngN7L-vSE

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is it , calling out the attacks etc , think my search is over

Comment: just need to find some episodes now

Comment: the starwing bit took me right back to sitting on a sat morning with ma cornflakes , awesome

Comment: @ped14 There’s so much overlap between the different version of combining mecha.

Comment: I appreciate ye taking the time to help bud , thank you

Comment: managed to find some episodes online under getter robo g,  english dubbed .. binge watching these tonight on night shift

Comment: the dome I mentioned is in it also just to confirm it is definitely the show ,